# How are Camel routes launched manually?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Camel route that is set to run every five minutes

```
@Component
public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder{
    private final String comment = "Cron"

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0/5+12-18+?+*+MON-FRI")
        .log("Processing from"+comment)
        .to("activemq:Totally.Rocks");
    }
}
```

And I want to force it to run manually, from Spring http request, and change *comment* field in CamelRoute

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ex/foos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getFoosBySimplePath() {
     //TODO: Start Camel route
     //change camel log "comment" from "Cron" to "HTTP request"
}
```

Comment: Is it that you want your timer/schedule to only start on a manual request to `/ext/foos`? When is your camel context started?

Comment: No, camel uses this "quartz2...." part to start route automatically. But sometimes i don't want to wait, and want to start same route by request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for my task was easy, although not straightforward if using Camel documentation:

> **startRoute**(**String** routeId) Starts the given route if it has been
>   previously stopped

I added another route

```
from("timer://manualRestart?repeatCount=1")
    .routeId("manualRestart")
    .noAutoStartup()
    .to("activemq:Totally.Rocks");
```

and use **startRoute()** to launch it when needed

```
public String getFoosBySimplePath() {
    camelContext.startRoute("manualRestart");
}
```

Why do I find it "not straightforward"? Because documentation says, that startRoute() can start previously stopped routes. Route was never stopped, it was configured not to start by default.

Answer (score 1):

To run a Camel route manually you can use [FluentProducerTemplate](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.19.3/org/apache/camel/FluentProducerTemplate.html). You can autowire an instance like a normal bean.

Examples: [1](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter7/springboot-rest-camel/src/main/java/camelinaction/HelloRestController.java), [2](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.camel.FluentProducerTemplate)

To be honest, I am not sure if it will work with quartz endpoints, but I am sure it is working pretty well with "direct:" endpoints. Anyway, it could be a good start for your findings.

Comment: This shoud be the accepted answer.